# Extra fields on CSV

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write my first Python script which prints what clients are probing for AP and what APs they're doing for. So my problem comes when a client (well, not client yet) probes for more than one AP.

```
import csv
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("usage: ./scriptpy.py csvfile")
    pass 
else:
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as csvfile:
        lector = csv.DictReader(csvfile, restkey='extra')
        for row in lector:
            print(row['Station MAC'] + " probes for " + row[' Probed ESSIDs'] + row['extra'])
            pass
```

this raises a KeyError in row[extra]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually csv files are text files. Are you sure this file is a bytes file to open it with `rb`?

Comment: What does "AP" stand for?

Comment: I used rb because that's the way in which Python reference of csv does. Access Point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to deal with key errors is `.get('my_key', 'alternate_value')`, like this:

```
row.get('extra', '') # rather than row['extra']
```